# Gateway route must define a match port if the parent Virtual Gateway has multiple listeners error in App Mesh cdk typescript v.gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-app-mesh

i get the following error "Gateway route must define a match port if the parent Virtual Gateway has multiple listeners." in my aws app mesh configuration, i have tried multiple fixes and even used a interface but for some reason cdk gives this error with my match port declared. Please find my code below;

```
const virtualGateway = new VirtualGateway(this, `${resourceId}-virtualGateway`, {
      mesh,
      virtualGatewayName: `${resourceId}-virtualGateway`,
      accessLog: AccessLog.fromFilePath('/dev/stdout'),
      listeners: [
        VirtualGatewayListener.http2({
          port: 8080,
          tls,
        }),
        VirtualGatewayListener.http2({
          port: 8081,
          tls
        }),
        VirtualGatewayListener.http2({
          port: 8082,
          tls,
        }),
      ],
    })
    virtualGateway.addGatewayRoute(`${resourceId}-gatewayRoute8080`, {
      routeSpec: GatewayRouteSpec.http2({
        routeTarget: virtualService,
        match: {
          port: 8080
        },
      }),
    })
    virtualGateway.addGatewayRoute(`${resourceId}-gatewayRoute8081`, {
      routeSpec: appmesh.GatewayRouteSpec.http2({
        routeTarget: virtualService,
        match: {
          port: 8081
        },
      }),
    })
    virtualGateway.addGatewayRoute(`${resourceId}-gatewayRoute8082`, {
      routeSpec: appmesh.GatewayRouteSpec.http2({
        routeTarget: virtualService,
        match: {
          port: 8082
        },
      }),
    })
```

i have tried creating an interface with the routeSpec and parsing that as the value for the routeSpec Variable to see if there is an issue identifying the match port but i still get the same error.